# Java Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: java, math

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class PythagoreanTheorem {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Get User Input
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sideA, sideB, hypothenuse;


        System.out.println("Please enter the value of sideA");
        sideA = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value of SideB");
        sideB = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Find the value of the hypothenuse
        hypothenuse = Math.sqrt((sideA*sideA)+(sideB*sideB));

        double roundOff = Math.round( hypothenuse * 100) / 100;

        System.out.println("The length of the hypothenuse is "  +   roundOff );         
    }

}
```

This code builds but doesn't show a general output.
I'm trying to display only 2 decimals from the hypotenuse.

Comment: `System.out.printf("The length of the hypothenuse is %.2f%n", hypothenuse);`

Comment: i have solved the problem but thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this:

```
 double roundOff = Math.round(hypothenuse * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Runing the code I has ex:

```
 Please enter the value of sideA
 232
 Please enter the value of SideB
 454
 The length of the hypothenuse is 509.84
```

Comment: @DhruvBhavsar Take special note of the numerator and denominator values, `100.0`.

Comment: that work do you  need other thing @DhruvBhavsar

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: I tested it that wotk @DhruvBhavsar

Comment: @Abdelhak it didnt work for me

Comment: thanks guys it finally worked aftera restart

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.format() to format the decimal number

```
System.out.println("The length of the hypothenuse is "  +   String.format("%.2f", roundOff));
```

Comment: where do i place this

Comment: Replace your System.out.println line with it, the last line of your code...

Comment: turns out i didnt need that

Comment: thanks for ur answer